# Getting error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path** when I run my app. Besides that, it crashes. I'm new at coding so, what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

This is the part of the code where the Logcat says is the error.

```
private void onPaymentSuccess(@NonNull final Response response) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, String> responseMap = gson.fromJson(
            Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),
            type
    );
    paymentIntentClientSecret = responseMap.get("clientSecret");
}
```

Comment: Depends on the json you're receiving. Looks like you're expecting an object but are receiving a string

Comment: Json which you are trying to parse is not a valid Json